# Binding to .aar does not create the classes contained, only the interfaces

Tags: c#, xamarin.android, java-binding

I have a very basic java module that contains two interfaces (IOrder, IOrderItem) and two classes that implement those interfaces (Order, OrderItem).

After creating a xamarin binding library in VS2017 I only see the two interfaces.

Checking out the api.xml shows me that both classes are recognized and I even see their generated classes in the obj\Debug\generated\src folder of my project.

Why aren't these classes making it into my object explorer?  What am I missing that links these generated files into the project itself?

Comment: I have a few common cases in my binding guide: https://gist.github.com/JonDouglas/dda6d8ace7d071b0e8cb

Comment: Late response, was on holidays the last few weeks.  Your guide was actually the first place I looked when I ran into the problem.  Solved this by removing and re-adding the binding project and rebuilding the binding it in release mode.  Maybe the the add/remove was unnecessary but wanted a fresh start.  I think the trick was building for release.